# What is the difference between "to keep/stand guard over the burned-out building" and "... on guard in front of the burned-out building"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

In the dictionary, they say

[**keep/stand guard (over somebody/something)**](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/guard)

["**Two police officers kept guard over the burned-out building.**"](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/guard_1?q=guard)

But if we change this sentence a bit to "**Two police officers kept guard in front of the burned-out building.**"

Some native speakers are for "**he is standing on guard in front of the house**" and against "**he is standing on guard over the house**" because they think "**over the house**" does not make any sense because the police is flying over the house or something.

Comment: If a native speaker doesn’t understand how the verb *guard* works, you need to stop asking that person about English.

Comment: I would use "over" because it's fewer words and fewer syllables than "in front of," and because it is a very common expression. As FeliniusRex said, someone who things "standing guard over the house" means "hovering in the air above the house" is not someone you should rely on for questions about English usage. [See also Google Ngrams.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stand+guard+over%2Cstand+guard+in+front+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true)

Comment: @FeliniusRex, but there are so many, which makes me think "over" is not suitable for the noun "guard"

Comment: @Tom Sorry, man. Ask different people. You may also want to double-check what they've told you in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiom **keep guard over** [something/someone] means to keep watch so that no harm comes to it, unauthorised people can't go in, or a person can't escape. It doesn't literally mean that the guard is standing above the place.

**Keep guard** *in front of* does have a literal meaning.